# Highcharts - only apply style to certain labels

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I want to be able to only bold the middle elements of a highcharts x axis. In the provided fiddle, is there any way to just bold the middle x-axis labels? (June or July)

http://jsfiddle.net/utnz2b9e/15/

Here is what I've tried to just bold all of the elements individually but I can't get it to work:

```
var chart = $('.actualPlansPlot').highcharts();
var xAxis = chart.xAxis[0];
for (var tick in xAxis.ticks) {
    if (xAxis.ticks[tick].label) {
        xAxis.ticks[tick].label.styles['fontWeight'] = 'bold';
    }
}
chart.redraw();
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this CSS:

```
.actualPlansPlot text:nth-child(6),
.actualPlansPlot text:nth-child(7) {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

It targets June and July.